# How can I set the vbscript, if clicked 'OK' then restart the computer?

Tags: vbscript

I have the following vb script:

```
X = msgbox("Save your work. Computer will restart!",64,"")
```

I would like the following:  If the user click the OK button, restart the computer.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the MessageBox is invoked, it pauses your script's execution. The script follows when user dismisses the MessageBox (via clicking OK or "X" in top right corner). If this does not works as You want, You can play with `vbYesNo` MsgBox.

So you can do the following:

```
X = msgbox("Save your work. Computer will restart!",64,"")

Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0"

'Where -r means restart,
' -t 0 means in no delay,
' You can also add -f flag, which forces restart.
```

You can find more options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc732503(v=ws.11))